# Angular 2 deep linking not working properly

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, deep-linking

I just start to learn Angular 2 and I have created an Angular 2 app with *Angular2VisualStudioTemplate* template. In my `app-routing.module.ts` I have the next routes declared:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'distribution', component: DistributionComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

The root component just has the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` directive.
In the `LoginComponent` view there is an input with `[routerLink]="['/dashboard']` directive so when the user click on the button you can navigate to `/dashboard`.

The problem is that if I want to navigate to `/dashboard` or any other path, typing the URL in the broswer's navigation bar it just doesn't work. The page just displays the login view and it doesn't change to the `dashboard` component or any other. Notice that I haven't implemented some login mechanism, there are just dummy views and components.

I've seen similar questions referring to problems like mine but I can't figured out how to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Who is serving your angular application? What's your backend?

Comment: I just run the app with `npm start`. I'm not thinking about the production environment yet.. @BunyaminCoskuner

Comment: Can you show us the html with the `routerLink`?

Comment: The input with the `routerLink` directive is:
`<input type="submit" value="Log In" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" />`. The whole file is a little big but it is plane html code

Comment: can you try adding this  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy},

Comment: Thanks @RahulSingh !! adding that line to my `app-routing.module.ts` solves the problem!

Comment: I'm not sure if this was an issue in earlier versions of Angular but if you don't place pathMatch: 'full' to you first path, ({ path: '', component: LoginComponent }) then the other paths underneath will never be reached. This is because it looks if your path contains the path in question, which they all do contain the starting empty path, and goes to your first path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can you try adding this {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy},

That comment provided by @RahulSingh was the solution for my problem. So the file `app-routing.module.ts` now looks something like:

```
/* code */
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
    ],
})
/* code */
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `app.module.ts` has this `import` array or similar?

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [ 
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
// other imports here 
], ...
 })
```

Comment: Yes, something like: `imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule]`. And inside my `AppRoutingModule` file `@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})`

Comment: Try adding this as the last option of your `routes`. `{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}`